# how to save values from inner query result from a subquery in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How to save inner query result from a subquery execution

```
select b.column1, a.column1, a.column2, a.column3 
from table1
where a.column4 = (select b.column1 from table2)
```

Can I get the combined result of 2 tables in subquery including inner query result?

Comment: What do you mean by *save values*? Please provide sample data and expected results that demonstrate what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: From the example you have given you can just take your sub-query and run it as a normal query to see the results. A lot of tools allow you to have two or more "Query result screens". For example, in SQL developer you can PIN the result of one query and then run the second query and in that way you can compare and analyse the results...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a join to me.

```
select b.column1, a.column1, a.column2, a.column3 
from table1 a join table2 b on a.column4 = b.column1
```